# What is a good source for older Crestline window locks?

Tags: windows, locks

I've been looking for two replacement locks for a Crestline window sash.  The window was purchased from Menard's in 1993.  I contacted Crestline about where to find the replacement locks and they gave me the name of two possibilites, neither of which have been able to provide the locks.  In the meantime I discovered that Crestline customer support is also Menard's customer support.  It's possible that Menard's owns Crestline.  After I mentioned that the windows were purchased from Menard's they were more helpful.  I sent them photos of the existing locks so they could see what I have.  They sent two locks for me to try with an alternate set I could order if the first set didn't work.  Neither set works.

I know the design of the locks changed because I successfully replaced a set on a different window several years ago but the current design doesn't work at all.

Does anyone know of sources for window parts or how I might be able to resolve this?

Kent

Comment: Posting the pictures might help

Answer (score 1):

Try [Blaine window hardware Inc.](http://www.blainewindow.com/) 800-678-1919

Comment: Thanks.  They were recommended by Crestline and don't have what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some success with [All-Glass Parts](http://allglassparts.com/).  Their online catalog generally includes all the measurements you would need to determine if a listed lock will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this site. I had been looking around for years and finally found this site and they have the replacement for my window.
 https://www.pwdservice.net/Crestline-Vetter-Double-Hung-Window-Sash-Lock-Brown

Comment: I've found that there are two designs. One lock fits flush with the top of the sash and the other lock has a lip that rests on top of the sash. I need the first kind.